# Independent increments in the Poisson process.

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, independence, poisson-process

Let $(N_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a Poisson process. For me, the definition is the following: $N_t=\max\{n\geq0:T_n\leq t\}$, where $T_0=0$ and $T_n=S_1+\ldots+S_n$, where $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ are independent exponential random variables of parameter $\lambda$ for all $n\geq1$. Hence, $N_t$ is Poisson$(\lambda t)$.

I was able to prove that $N_{t+s}-N_s$ is independent of $N_s$ and that $N_{t+s}-N_s\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$, for $s,t\geq0$. From the information I wrote, is there a relatively easy way to prove that $N_{t+s}-N_s$ is independent from $(N_{s_1},\ldots,N_{s_m})$ for all $0\leq s_1\leq \ldots\leq s_m\leq s$ and $m\geq1$?

Comment: Are you interested in alternative proofs?

Comment: @saz I am looking for a proof just using $N_{t+s}-N_s\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ and $N_{t+s}-N_s$ independent of $N_s$. I know that there are books, notes... that prove the independence of the increments, but I would like a proof just using these two facts.

Comment: @user39756 I have rephrased your question to clarify it a bit more. Is this form of the question ok? If it is not, feel free to delete my version.

Comment: @Dominik Yes, the form of the question is perfect. I know that there are direct proofs for the independence of the increments, but I was interested on having a (maybe easy) proof from just those 3 axioms-properties. If all of you think that it is better to have a direct proof of the independence, as it is usually done in notes and books, just tell me.

Comment: @William I didn't change the meaning of the question. It was never asked to show that the Poisson process has the Markov property or independent increments - OP already confirmed that there are many books and references that proof this. The question was whether these properties can be concluded from the properties that OP has already proven. I have only made this more clear with my edited question. And OP also confirmed in the comments that this is exacly what was meant in the question. This question has nothing to do with the difference between the Markov property and independent increments.

Comment: @William But the question body never asked to prove the Markov property. From the first version on, OP stated 'From the information I wrote [...]', i.e. he assumes only the properties (!!) that he has proven and wants to infer further properties.

Comment: You are still talking about the Markov vs independent increment question, when his does **NOT** matter. OP wants to prove the Markov property *only* from the properties that he has already proven, not from the structure of $N_t$ as the maximum stated in the beginning of the question. Your answer does everything *but* answer this question. You start with the representation $N_t = \max\{\ldots\}$ and prove the properties. But you should start with "$N_0 = 0$", "$N_{t + s} - N_s \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$" and "$N_{s + t} - N_s$ is independent from $N_s$".

Comment: @Dominik No that's not accurate, I use $N_{t+s} - N_s \sim Poisson(\lambda t)$ explicitly, and the rest of the proof is the same as OP's proof that $N_{s+t} - N_s$ is independent of $N_s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from what you have shown, using a similar argument and the memory-less property characterizing the exponential distribution, that the Poisson process has **independent increments**. See [page. 9 of this document](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-PP.pdf), or even better the [remark on p.4 here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~wka/math135/newpoisson.pdf), or the best so far [theorem 3.3.5 on page 6 here](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.110/lehre/ws13/Stochastik_II/Skript_3.pdf). Also [pp. 3-4 here.](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/statistik/lehre/WS1314/BachelorWT/Daten/StPro_Ross1.pdf)

[*Independent increments imply the Markov property*](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/math-136/Markov_note.pdf). In particular, what you have shown allows you to show that the Poisson process has the Markov property.

From the Markov property, we know that $N_{t+s}-N_s$ is independent from the sigma algebra $\mathscr{F}_s$.

Since all of the $s_i \le s$, we have by definition of $\mathscr{F}_s$ that all of the $N_{s_i}$ are measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}_s$. Since each of $N_{s_1}, \dots, N_{s_m}$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}_s$, it follows that the joint distributioin of $(N_{s_1}, \dots, N_{s_m})$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}_s$.

Since $N_{t+s} - N_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$, and $(N_{s_1}, \dots, N_{s_m})$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}_s$, it follows that $N_{t+s}-N_s$ is independent of $(N_{s_1},\dots,N_{s_m})$, which is what we wanted to show.

**Proof of independent increments #1** (use induction)

Let $0:=s_0 < s_1 < \dots < s_m$ be given. Then by what you have already showed, $N_{s_2}- N_{s_1}$ is independent of $N_{s_1}$. This is the base case of our induction.

Now assume by means of induction that $N_{s_n}-N_{s_{n-1}}$ is independent of $N_{s_2} -N_{s_1}, \dots, N_{s_{n-1}} - N_{s_{n-2}}$ and that all of these are independent of each other.

By what you have shown, $N_{s_{n+1}}-N_{s_n}$ is independent of $N_{s_n}$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322688/induction-proof-on-independent-increment-property).

<strike>Using a telescoping sum representation, we have that $N_{s_n} = (N_{s_n} - N_{s_{n-1}}) + N_{s_{n-1}} = (N_{s_n} - N_{s_{n-1}}) $.</strike>

Thus $N_{s_{n+1}}-N_{s_n} $ is independent of $(N_{s_n} - N_{s_{n-1}})$ as well as of $$N_{s_{n-1}}= (N_{s_2} - N_{s_1}) + \dots + (N_{s_1} - N_{s_2}) \,.$$ Since $N_{s_{n-1}}$ is the sum of mutually independent random variables $(N_{s_2} -N_{s_1}, \dots, N_{s_{n-1}} - N_{s_{n-2}}, N_{s_n}-N_{s_{n-1}})$, and $N_{s_{n+1}}-N_{s_n}$ is independent of it, it follows that $(N_{s_{n+1}}-N_{s_n})$ is independent of all of the R.V.'s in the sum. This completes the proof of the induction step and thus one proof of independent increments.

**Proof of independent increments #2** (following Durrett's *Probability Theory and Examples*, pp. 155-156, 4th edition)   $\newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}}$

$N_t = \max \{ n \ge 0: T_n \le t  \}$ where $T_0 = 0$ and $T_n = S_1+ \dots S_n$, $S_n \sim \exp(\lambda)$ i.i.d. RV's.

Already shown: $N_{t+s} - N_s$ is independent of $N_s$ for all $s,t \ge 0$.

Let $T_1' = T_{N_t +1} - s$ be the amount of time that elapses after time $s$ until the next arrival. The following computation shows that $T_1'$ is independent of $N_s$: $$\Prob(T_1' \ge t|N_s = n) = \Prob(T_{N_s+1}  \ge (s+t) | N_s = n) \\ = \Prob(T_{n+1} \ge (s+t), T_n \le s  )/ \Prob(N_s = n)\,.$$ The numerator equals: $$ \Prob(T_{n+1} \ge (s+t), T_n \le s ) = \int_0^s f_{T_n}(u) \Prob(S_{n+1} \ge (s+t) - u)du \\= \int_0^s \frac{\lambda^n u^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda u} e^{-\lambda( (s+t) -u)}du = e^{-\lambda (s+t)}\frac{\lambda t^n}{n!}. $$ By what you have already shown, the denominator is $\Prob(N_t=n) = e^{-\lambda s}(\lambda s)^n/n!$, so: $$\Prob(T_{n+1} \ge (s+t)| N_s = n) = \frac{e^{- \lambda(s+t)}}{e^{-\lambda s}} = e^{-\lambda t} =\Prob(T_1' \ge t)  \,. $$

For $k \ge 2$, define $T_k' = T_{N_t +k} - T_{N_t +k-1}$, the amount of time elapsing between the $(k-1)$th arrival after time $s$ and the $k$th arrival after time $s$. Observing that: $$\Prob(T_n \le s, T_{n+1} \ge u, T_{n+k} - T_{n+k-1} \ge v_k, k=2,\dots,K) = \Prob(T_{n} \le s, T_{n+1} \ge u) \prod_{k=2}^{K} \Prob(S_{n+k} \ge v_k) \,, $$ it follows that the $T_1', T_2', \dots$ are i.i.d. and independent of $N_t$. In other words, arrivals after time $s$ are independent of $N_s$ and have the same distribution as the original sequence.

From this follows the desired conclusion of independent increments, namely that if $0:= s_0 < s_1 < \dots < s_m$ then $N_{s_i} - N_{s_i - 1}$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ are independent.

This is because the vector $( N_{s_2} - N_{s_1}, \dots, N_{s_m} - N_{s_m -1}  )$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(T_k', k \ge 1)$ and thus independent of $N_{s_1}$. Then it follows by induction: $$\Prob(N_{s_i} - N_{s_{i- 1}} = k_1, i = 1, \dots, n) = \prod_{i=1}^m \exp (-\lambda (s_i - s_{i-1})) \frac{\lambda  (s_i - s_{i-1} )^{k_i}}{k_i!}\\ = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \Prob(N_{s_i} - N_{s_{i-1}} = k_i) \,. \square $$

The fact that $T_1'$ is independent of $N_s$ amounts essentially to the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. **Note:** I imagine this is similar to the argument that you used to show that $N_{s+t}-N_s$ is independent of $N_s$. The only difference here is that now we are renewing the process at a random time, as opposed to a deterministic time.

**Proof that independent increments imply the Markov property** (see [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/math-136/Markov_note.pdf))

In order to demonstrate that the process is Markov, it suffices to show (for any bounded measurable function $f$) that: $$\mathbb{E}[f(N_{s+t})|\mathscr{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[f(N_{s+t})|\sigma(N_s)] \,. $$ This follows from the fact that: $$\mathbb{E}[f(N_{s+t})|\mathscr{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[f(\ [N_{s+t} - N_s]\  + N_s)| \mathscr{F}_s] \,.$$ By assumption, $N_{s+t} - N_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$, and by definition $N_s$ is $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable. Thus the desired equality follows immediately from the above. In other words, $$\mathbb{E}[f(\ [N_{s+t} - N_s]\  + N_s)| \mathscr{F}_s] \mathbb{E}[f(N_{s+t} \underbrace{- N_s + N_s}_{=0})|\sigma(N_s)] = \mathbb{E}[f(N_{s+t})|\sigma(N_s) ] \,.$$

Comment: Aside from the fact that the answer of Did considers a discrete process, he assumes that all the increments are independent - not only that $N_{t + s} - N_s$ is independent of $N_s$. The complicated part of this question is showing whether this independence implies the independence of all the increments.

Comment: OP assumes that $N_{t + s} - N_s$ is independent of $N_s$, but you assume the stronger condition that $N_{t + s} - N_s$ is independent of e.g. $(N_s - N_{s - s'}, N_{s - s'})$.

Comment: In your proof, you assume that $N_{t + s} - N_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$. However, this is *not* OPs assumption; Your assumption is much stronger.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the sigma-algebra *jointly generated by all* $N_t$, where $t \le s$. In contrast, $\sigma(N_s) \subset \mathcal{F}_s$ is the sigma-algebra generated only by $N_s$. OP does not assume that the Markov property holds.

Comment: You are linking to some sources that show that Poisson processes have independent increments - and OP knows that there are many proofs of this. But the question is whether we can directly conclude this from the things that OP has already shown, i.e. if $N$ is a process where $N_{t + s} - N_s$ is poisson-distributed with parameter $\lambda t$ and independent of $N_s$, does $N$ necessarily have independent increments?

Comment: @Dominik I am precisely interested on the proof of the remark in page 4 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~wka/math135/newpoisson.pdf). Why that sentence "Applying the preceding Corollary repeatedly we infer that..."?

Comment: @user39756 It means use induction. See my most recent edit.

Comment: You seem to be fixated on the property of independent increments vs. Markov property. But this is besides the question that OP asked. He has proven some properties of the Poisson process and asks if we can deduce only from the *known properties* that the process satisfies the Markov (or in this case equivalent: the independent increments) property. So this question doesn't ask for the specific properties of the Poisson process, but rather under which minimal conditions on a process we can infer that it is Poisson.

Comment: @Dominik I am not fixated on that, you are misunderstanding. There is a theorem of which I am also well aware that the Poisson process is characterized by its independent increments and some other things. But the proper way to define it is constructively as the OP has done and as my answer does and then infer these properties (which turn out to be uniquely characterizing of the Poisson process, but this is by no means a priori evident). This answer uses the properties of the construction of the process given, and the OP's known properties. If you actually read this answer, you would know that.

Comment: Why does $(N_{s_{n+1}}-N_{s_n})$ need to be independent from all the summands? You try to show that when $X$ is independent of $Y + Z$ and $Y$ is independent of $Z$, then $X$ is also independent of $(Y, Z)$. Why should this be correct?

Comment: @Dominik Oh you're right again, that proof only works for the Gaussian R.V.'s in Brownian motion. In any case Durrett's proof should still work.