# Compensated Poisson process is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, poisson-process

Suppose $N_{t}$ is an adapted Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. One defines the compensated Poisson process by $M_{t} := N_{t} - \lambda t$. I am trying to show that the compensated process is a martingale. I need to show that

1. $M_{t}$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_{t}$,
2. $M_{t}$ is integrable,
3. for $s < t$, $\mathbb{E}(M_{t} | \mathcal{F}_{s}) = M_{s}$.

I am having trouble with $1$ and $3$. For question $1$, I know that $N_{t}$ is adapted by assumption, but why is $N_{t} - \lambda t$ adapted? The definition of adapted says that $N_{t} - \lambda t$ must be $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ measurable; I don't immediately see why this is the case. Perhaps it is something to do with the fact that translations of measurable random variables are measurable?

For question $3$, we calculate

\begin{aligned}\mathbb{E}(N_{t} - \lambda t ~|~ \mathcal{F}_{s}) &= \mathbb{E}(N_{t} - N_{s}~ |~\mathcal{F}_{s}) + \mathbb{E}(N_{s} - \lambda t ~|~ \mathcal{F}_{s}) \\[1ex]
&= \mathbb{E}(N_{t} - N_{s})  + N_{s} - \lambda t,\end{aligned}

but I don't understand why $\mathbb{E}(N_{s} - \lambda t ~|~ \mathcal{F}_{s}) = N_{s} - \lambda t$. I assume that $N_{s} - \lambda t$ must be $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ -measurable as then this follows from properties of conditional expectation. But why is this the case? I get that $N_{s}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{s}$ -measurable by hypothesis but I don't see why $N_{s} - \lambda t$ is.

I guess my basic probability theory is rusty so I would appreciate if someone could spell out the argument for me, thank you!

Comment: Deterministic translations of measurable RVs are measurable. This is completely trivial when you consider that $x\mapsto x-\lambda t$ is a continuous, hence, measurable Borel function that you compose with your $N_t$. Regarding point 3: you show this by using that $N_t-\lambda t$ has [independent increments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2068730/949989) that have expectation zero. Same proof that worked for showing that Brownian motion is a martingale.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for clearing it up. If you would like to submit an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. It may be better when you either edit the question or write your own answer. To start with $\mathbb{E}(N_{t} - \lambda t ~|~ \mathcal{F}_{s}) = \mathbb{E}(N_{t} - N_{s}~ |~\mathcal{F}_{s}) + \mathbb{E}(N_{s} - \lambda t ~|~ \mathcal{F}_{s})$ is not the smartest approach. You need a $\lambda(t-s)$ somewhere.

Comment: @KurtG. Ok sure I will write my own answer then. But why shouldn't we start like that? Because we know that $N_{t} - N_{s}$ has mean $\lambda (t-s)$ by definition of the Poisson process (at least the definition I was given) so then we can say $\mathbb{E}(N_{t} - N_{s} ~|~\mathcal{F}_{s}) = \mathbb{E}(N_{t} - N_{s}) =  \lambda (t-s)$ by virtue of independent increments

Comment: That's right. See why I asked you to do it? Perhaps I thought that your start did not exactly resemble the BM proof. I use to replace $W_t$ by $N_t-\lambda t\,.$ Both have independent increments with expectation zero.

Comment: @KurtG. To be honest I don't understand why you asked me to do it, but its ok my questions have been answered

Comment: "To be honest I don't understand why you asked me to do it" - presumably, one would not be allowed to consult MSE on an exam, for instance. Writing your own answer is the best way to be sure you understand.